# How to get images to return to another location on a website when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

followup to my other question that wasn't explained properly.

This is a demo of an "alpha" version of what I am trying to get.
   http://jsfiddle.net/Hotmanics/fd8jg/)

CSS

```
#container
{
width:960px;
height:500px;
background:#36F;        
}

#imagesn
{
width:200px;
height:500px;
background-color:#666;
position:relative;
overflow:scroll;
}

#hi
{
width:150px;
height:100px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="imagesn">Hello
<div id="hi"><img src="" width="150px" height="100px" />

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve to where when I click on an element or an Image, then it will move and enlarge the image to the right side of the `<div id="container">`, while at the same time keeping the image on the left the same.

Comment: first you should try sth. yourself before asking

Comment: I have no leads to begin, that is the issue

Comment: There are so many ways to attack this problem. You could use a lightbox effect. You could create an animation.

Comment: Here's a simple fiddle that might get you started. Just click on the picture. http://jsfiddle.net/PP27t/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/6x6bj/)**</kbd>

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="imagesn">Hello
    <div id="hi">
      <img src="http://curitibainenglish.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Tech-eye.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.onesullivan.com/uploads/defense_tech.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="large"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #36F; 
}
#imagesn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#hi {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#hi img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#large {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  width: 760px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('#hi img').click(function() {
    if($('.large').length < 1) {
       $('#large').append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" class="large">');
    }
    else {
       $('.large').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));   
    }
  });
});
```